# Asp.Net MVC file upload to FTP return 550 error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Sorry for my English, I hope i can explain myself.

When we try to file upload to FTP server from Internet Explorer it returns 550 error code. 
But our code works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Here my method

```
public void UploadImageToFtp(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile, string path, int w, int h)
{
    if (uploadfile != null)
    {
        var uploadurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FtpPath").ToString();
        var uploadfilename = uploadfile.FileName;
        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FtpUserName").ToString();
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FtpPass").ToString();
        var img = Image.FromStream(uploadfile.InputStream, true, true);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img, w, h);
        string bmFolder = path;
        string ftppath = uploadurl + bmFolder + "/" + uploadfile.FileName;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bm.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            string directoryToCreate = uploadurl + path;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(directoryToCreate);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            client.UploadData(ftppath, ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing that obviously differs between useragents in the code pasted is the contents of uploadfile, compare it during chrome/IE requests and see whats different.

Comment: You forget to dispose `bm`.

Comment: Is that a problem for IE ?

Comment: No, your code is on the server, but it needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks i'll do it.